# Google place API get input text from Autocomplete form

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api

So here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/q8XS6/)
Everithing is ok and easy. But, how to get the dirrect input text from Autocomplete form? WHOLE text value?

If you call `.getPlace()` you get structured info, but I need to get the same text from input field as user typed into.

```
var place = tbgeo.getPlace();

// How to get something like this => var userinput = tbgeo.InnerText;

console.log(JSON.stringify(place));

var lat = place.geometry["location"]["k"]
var lng = place.geometry["location"]["D"]

var address = '';
if (place.address_components) {
    address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
    ].join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
<div ng-app="">

<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="userInputText" ></p>
Bind Name: <input type="text" ng-model="userInputText" >

<!-- or use ng-bind instead of ng-model -->
<p ng-bind="userInputText"></p>

</div>
```